# Could not connect to nuget feed

Tags: iis-7.5, nuget-server

I try to use private nuget feed, so I've made steps from the second part of instruction: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds
But when I try to connect from Visual Studio to this feed I received message: "Could not connect to the feed specified at 'http://localhost:90/nuget/'. Please verify that the package source (located in the Package Manager Settings) is valid and ensure your network connectivity."
Could anyone met with the familiar issue?
I host it in IIS 7.5, Windows 7, nuget.server version 2.0.1

Experimentally I've added directory as nuget feed location and that is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. When I updated nuget package manager in Visual Studio everything works fine.